# FileNotFoundException while importing a spring xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have the following line in one of my xml file to include the `spring.xml` file located at `src/main/resources/config` of my maven project.

```
<import resource="classpath:config/spring.xml"/>
```

I have the location `src/main/resources` in my build path. Despite this while running it. It is giving the below exception

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
... 13 more
```

Below is the build path source tab

[image]

**src/main/resources/** :

[image]

EDIT :
For some reason my target folder does not have classes folder as well

[image]

EDIT : After clean install I get the below folders in the target folder:

[image]

EDIT : pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringHibernateExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <!-- <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version> -->
        <hibernate.version>3.6.9.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The classes folder is present in the location where the imported project is but somehow not visible in the eclipse project structure

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put `/` before `config`. Like this:

```
classpath:/config/spring.xml
```

EDIT: Put the `Excluded` of resources path to `(None)` and `Included: (All)`

Comment: No, Still the same exception

Comment: I guess your using Maven to build your project... plz verify that your spring.xml file exists in your Maven projects target directory (where the compiled java classes are put), e.g. here: `<MAVEN_PROJECT_ROOT>/target/classes/config/spring.xml`

Comment: @TommyBrettschneider I have /target/maven-status in my project which does not contain the above path. Is there any maven command to run to produce these folders?

Comment: in general, if your project is setup a usual maven project with maven's directory structure (src\main\java, src\main\resources, src\test\java, src\test\resources) and a pom.xml file in the project's root directory, calling the maven goals "clean" and "install" should do the trick... on cmdline:

`<MAVEN_PROJECT_DIR>\mvn clean install`

afterwards there should be a target folder with all the compiled classes and the files of the src/.../resource folders.

Comment: there`s also a maven "run" goal, so please make sure you start your application correctly or setup your classpath manually to include all relevant directories and files...

Comment: @TommyBrettschneider still not getting the classes folder in the target folder..Edited the question

Comment: can you post your pom.xml file...?